# Python if statement issue

Tags: python, validation, if-statement

I am new at Python and in this below function i am trying to do some validation process.

```
def countUpToTen(counter):
    if type(counter) is not int or counter == None:
        print("Invalid parameter!")
    if counter > 10:
        print("Counter can not be greater than 10!")
        return False
    else:
        count = 1
        while (count <= counter):
           print 'The count is:', count
           count = count + 1
        print("Done counting !")

countUpToTen("0s")
```

But when i call it like `countUpToTen("0s")` it prints `Invalid parameter!` and                                                                                                                                             `Counter can not be greater than 10!` but i expect just `Invalid parameter!`. I dont know how it compares a string with a number in second if statement. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: You don't return after the `if type(counter) is...` branch, so the code keeps going. Also the `or counter == None` is redundant; None is not an integer type.

Comment: Note: `not isinstance(counter, int)` is preferred to `type(counter) is not int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not exiting the function after printing the first error message.

In Python 2, you can still compare strings and integers, with numbers *always lower* than anything else (except `None`), so the second `if` statement also matches:

```
>>> '0s' > 10
True
```

Python 3 does away with supporting comparisons between arbitrary types and comparing `int` with `str` raises an exception instead.

In this case, you should use `return` to exit the function early when the parameter is invalid:

```
if type(counter) is not int or counter == None:
    print("Invalid parameter!")
    return
```

Note that the Pythonic way to test for a type is to use `isinstance()`. You should test for `None` using the `is` identity test as `None` is a singleton object, but the test is redundant here; if `counter` is `None` it is not an instance of `int` *either*. The following suffices:

```
if not isinstance(counter, int):
    print("Invalid parameter!")
    return
```

Instead of returning early, consider using `elif` for the next test:

```
if not isinstance(counter, int):
    print("Invalid parameter!")
elif counter > 10:
    print("Counter can not be greater than 10!")
else:
    # etc.
```

Note that you are almost certainly using Python 2 and thus using too many parentheses. `print` in Python 2 is a statement, not a function, and using parentheses *anyway* can lead to you trying to print tuples:

```
>>> print('This is a tuple', 'with two values')
('This is a tuple', 'with two values')
>>> print 'This is just', 'two values'
This is just two values
```

You probably already discovered this because you are using `print` with two arguments and no parentheses in one location already.

The test for your `while` loop also doesn't need to use parentheses:

```
while count <= counter:
```

Instead of using `while` and incrementing `count` manually, just use a `for` loop and `range()`:

```
if not isinstance(counter, int):
    print "Invalid parameter!"
elif counter > 10:
    print "Counter can not be greater than 10!"
else:
    for count in range(1, counter + 1):
       print 'The count is:', count
```

The latter loop can also be written as:

```
for count in range(counter):
   print 'The count is:', count + 1
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be _always lower_ than anything else except `None`?

Comment: @Yoel: yeah, CPython sorts `None` before everything else indeed. These orderings are all classified as 'implementation details', of course.

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite the if/else statements slightly to make it an if/elif/else construct:

```
def countUpToTen(counter):
    if type(counter) is not int or counter == None:
        print("Invalid parameter!")
    elif counter > 10:
        print("Counter can not be greater than 10!")
        return False
    else:
        count = 1
        while (count <= counter):
            print 'The count is:', count
            count = count + 1
        print("Done counting !")

countUpToTen("0s")
```

This would also give the output you expect.